# Permission Table

Tags: c#, mysql

I need some help to resolve a doubt.
I have 27 states and 5700 cities, and I would like to give permission to my users so that they access or not each state or city.
Read 5700 cities each time an user try to access the system is not a good idea, because they has to "download" all the information of the table to know who can access each city.
I'm thinking in give "binary permission", putting 5700 bits with 2 possibilities, 0 (not accessible) or 1 (accessible), then the system can read each bit and compare with a list of cities and give or not permission.
What's the best solution to this problem? Any other math possibility to optimize this permission check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create a many-to-many table with 2 columns:

- userid
- cityid

and only put a record in there if the user has access to the city.

This will be much easier to manage and selection of the proper cities for a user will be easy too.

Comment: This is the way I do today, but depending of the user connection the download of the table take a considerable time, and this action delays the user login, mostly if the user have full access or nearly so. I have more than 5000 lines in DB for each user that have full access, the idea of "binary permission" is keep 1 line for each user with: userid, state1, state2, state3... state27, then each state have a fixed number of cities, so the input will be like this: userid (1), state1 - eg.that have 10 cities - (0100000001) and so on.. that way the user 1 have access to city 2 and 10 of first state

Comment: You can get all the information in one query joining the new table and cities based on the user id.